# Reactjs getting a state value from a child (with hookReducer) to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a simple counter using

useReducer to manage the state up to here

no problem.

I'm not sure how to pass the

current state to the parent component

if I try to use the handler in the click event like

```
const handlerMinus = () => {
    dispatch({ type: Action.MINUS });
    handler(state);
  };
```

but I get the old value.

So I manage to use useEffect

### // Update

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!firstMounded.current) {
      handler(state.value);
    }
    firstMounded.current = false;
  }, [state]);
```

It seems to work but I'm not very proud of it :)

Is there a better standard way to get the state from the parent?

All code

```
export interface CounterState {
  value: number;
}
export interface CounterProps {
  color?: string;
  value?: number | string;
  handler: (value: number) => void;
}

enum Action {
  MINUS = "ADD",
  PLUS = "DELETE",
  RESET = "DONE"
}
type Actions =
  | { type: Action.MINUS }
  | { type: Action.PLUS }
  | { type: Action.RESET };

const initialCounterState: CounterState = { value: 0 };

const reducer = (state: CounterState, action: Actions): CounterState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Action.MINUS:
      return { value: state.value > 0 ? state.value - 1 : state.value };
    case Action.PLUS:
      return { value: state.value + 1 };
    case Action.RESET:
      return { value: 0 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const Counter = ({ color, value, handler }: CounterProps) => {
  if (value) {
    initialCounterState.value = Number(value);
  }
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialCounterState);
  const firstMounded = useRef(true);
  const c = color ?? "gray.500";

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!firstMounded.current) {
      handler(state.value);
    }
    firstMounded.current = false;
  }, [state]);

  const handlerMinus = () => {
    dispatch({ type: Action.MINUS });
  };

  const handlerPlus = async () => {
    dispatch({ type: Action.PLUS });
  };

  return (
    <Flex
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="space-between"
      borderWidth={1}
      borderColor={c}
      borderRadius="md"
    >
      <IconButton
        onClick={handlerMinus}
        variant="outline"
        aria-label="minus"
        icon={<HiMinusSm size="20" />}
        borderWidth={0}
        borderRightWidth={1}
        borderRightColor={c}
        borderRightRadius="0"
        color={c}
        _hover={{
          background: "white",
          color: c
        }}
        _active={{
          background: "white",
          color: c
        }}
      />
      <Box fontFamily="Menlo" fontSize="xl">
        {state.value}
      </Box>
      <IconButton
        onClick={handlerPlus}
        variant="outline"
        aria-label="plus"
        icon={<HiPlusSm size="20" />}
        borderWidth={0}
        borderLeftWidth={1}
        borderLeftColor={c}
        borderLeftRadius="0"
        color={c}
        _hover={{
          background: "white",
          color: c
        }}
        _active={{
          background: "white",
          color: c
        }}
      />
    </Flex>
  );
};

const Product = ({ product }: ProductProps) => {
  const url = `/images/products/${product.image}`;
  const handlerCounter = (value: number) => {
    console.log( value);
  };
  return (
    <Flex>
      <Box>
        <Image
          className="image"
          loader={productImageloader}
          src={url}
          alt={product.name}
          layout="fill"
          objectFit="contain"
        />
      </Box>
      // other stuff
      <Counter handler={handlerCounter} />
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your title is to get state value from child to parent, but your last question is getting state from the parent? Both are very different

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Perhaps some examples and formatting would help? I've done my best to answer based on what you have provided

Comment: @Isaac I posted all the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would be better to surface the reducer state to the top most parent that actually needs to consume it. In this case, that would be the parent (it won't need to go up to the grand-parent, just the highest consumer).

Parent can then pass down the dispatch to the child as noted in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down

Comment: I thought the same but not sure it was the best option. Thank for help :)

Comment: mmm I have to use the counter in a product component so do I have to wrap each product with context ? all in all if i buy one product i don't want to buy them all :)

Comment: context wouldn't be needed in this case. its hard to tell without seeing the rest, but lets say your structure is "product-list" > "product (parent)" > "minus button (child)". i would place this reducer at the parent level which has no concept of other products

Comment: Do you mean put the userReducer in the parent (product component) and simply pass increment decrement and value to the props children (counter component) ? still don't like me but if there no other way. BTW I updated the post with a simply bad way :) - I think i will use jotai for the cart component so in case I made a quick refactoring - again thanks for the help :)

Comment: I've had posted the whole code

Comment: Based on your update, I would still have the reducer in the product and pass the dispatch down (or alternatively you could pass down individual handlers increment/decrement, but you can pass down the whole dispatch). 
I actually use Zustand (same team as Jotai) - both are good options. However, its probably good to have a solid grasp of state flow first - Jotai isn't a silver bullet